# How to read a specific line of a RSS feed in visual C#

Tags: rss, visual-c#-express-2010, rss-reader

I want to read a specific line of a RSS feed to display the information in a Label using visual C#. Given below is the Rss feed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"><channel>
<title>Weather Underground</title>
    <link>http://www.wunderground.com/</link>
    <category>weather</category>
<item>
    <title>Current Conditions : 28C, Mostly Cloudy - 9:10 AM IST Jun. 28</title>
    <link>http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/43466.html</link>
    <description><![CDATA[Temperature: 28&deg;C | Humidity: 79% | Pressure: 1011hPa            (Steady) | Conditions: Mostly Cloudy | Wind Direction: SW | Wind Speed: 15km/h<img src="http://server.as5000.com/AS5000/adserver/image?ID=WUND-00071&C=0" width="0" height="0"  border="0"/>]]>
    </description>
    <pubDate>Thu, 28 Jun 2012 09:10:00 IST</pubDate>
</item>

<item>
    <title>Forecast for Wednesday Night as of Jun. 27 5:30 PM IST</title>
    <link>http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/43466.html</link>    
    <description>
    Chance of a Thunderstorm. Low:26 &amp;deg; C.
     </description>
     <pubDate>Wed, 27 Jun 2012 12:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
     <guid isPermaLink="false">1340798400-1-night</guid>
  </item>

  <item>
      <title>Forecast for Thursday as of Jun. 27 5:30 PM IST</title>
       <link>http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/43466.html</link>
       <description>
        Chance of a Thunderstorm. High:31 &amp;deg; C.//This is the line that I need
      </description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 27 Jun 2012 12:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">1340884800-2-day</guid>
   </item>
```

There are many Item tags in this XML file how do I refer to the one that i need and get the text inside that description tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may do something  like this read all the description to a list and then get specific description from a list

```
    var rss = XDocument.Load("your rss file");
    var items = (from c in rss.Descendants("item") select new{
                 Title  = (string)c.Element("description")      
                }).ToList();

// first description 

    string firstitem= items[0].Title.ToString();
```

Comment: When I do this: var rss = XDocument.Load("your rss file"); It says cannot assign void to an implicitly typed local variable.

Comment: try this XDocument rss = XDocument.Load("your rss file");

Comment: Thanks. I have included the wrong important statement now that's okay. But there's another thing it says the name 'item' does not exist in the current context:  Title  = (string)item.Element("description")